DBT Seed change Schema from default schema
While creating my project, I have provided a default schema name from Snowflake to work in the project, let's call it DEFAULT_SCHEMA,
I tried updating the schema to a different one for SEEDS in dbt_project.yml,
SEEDS:
PROJECT_NAME:
+SCHEMA: SEED_SCHEMA_NAME
However, when I run DBT Seed command, DBT instead created a new SCHEMA as:
DEFAULT_SCHEMA_SEED_SCHEMA_NAME
Is there any other property I need to override?

After going through the documentation, it appears that this is the default behavior of DBT, to update this, we need to change the following macro as:
{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}

{%- set default_schema = target.schema -%}
{%- if custom_schema_name is none -%}

    {{ default_schema }}

{%- else -%}

   {{ custom_schema_name | trim }}

{%- endif -%}

{%- endmacro %}

